# element not found error is displayed when I m trying to find and work on the element by using switch to window

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

class SwtWin():

```
def swwn(self):
    driver=webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("https://learn.letskodeit.com/p/practice")
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    ParentWin=driver.current_window_handle
    print(ParentWin)
    driver.find_element_by_id("openwindow").click()
    windows=driver.window_handles
    print(windows)
    for Tab in windows:
          print(Tab)
          if Tab != ParentWin:
             print("Switched to sub window")
             driver.switch_to.window(Tab)
             print(Tab)
             sel=driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Login")
             sel.click()
             driver.close()
             break
    driver.switch_to.window(ParentWin)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 1000);")
    driver.quit()
```

SwtWin().swwn()[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element can't be found if the search for an element is run prior to the element appears on the page.

In the given code, when `driver.find_element_by_id("openwindow").click()` is executed, it opens a new page and `sel=driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Login")` fails as the element wasn't rendered (network issues, slow laptop, etc.).

The standard solution, in this case, is to use `WebDriverWait` class in order to wait for a state of the element and, only if the desired state appears (for instance, presence of an element on a page), to continue the execution.

Here is the sample

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://learn.letskodeit.com/p/practice")
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
ParentWin = driver.current_window_handle
print(ParentWin)
driver.find_element_by_id("openwindow").click()
windows = driver.window_handles
print(windows)
for Tab in windows:
    print(Tab)
    if Tab != ParentWin:
        print("Switched to sub window")
        driver.switch_to.window(Tab)
        print(Tab)
        # wait until "Login" appers on the page
        sel = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(
                (By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Login")
            )
        )
        # work with login button
        sel.click()
        driver.close()
        break
driver.switch_to.window(ParentWin)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 1000);")
driver.quit()
```